# Using a load balancer that requires oAuth to protect my backend application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-oauth

I have a backend service, which I don't want to be expose, and also, just the employees that uses Gsuite oAuth should access.

Instead of exposing the backend and add the logic of oauth in it, I looked at the [vouch-proxy](https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy) project, which fits me very well (a proxy that redirects unauthenticated traffic to oauth login page and then, when a valid token is passed, it's redirect to the backend.

Before using this vouch proxy, do GCP has something built-in for it? Or another kind of setup that my backend service is not exposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud provides the [Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto) that would precisely fit your needs since it's integrating well with [G Suite domain](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g_suite_domain) and can sit in front of your Load-Balancer.